# Trying to find the next prime number, not sure whats wrong. Java

Tags: java, primes

im fairly new to Java and just cant figure out why my program is not working. Anything anyone can do to help would be appreciated!

```
public class LabOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please input a number: \n");

        int inputReceive = 44;
        int nextPrime = inputReceive;
        int n = 5;
        boolean isprime=true;

        do {
            if(inputReceive <= 1)
                isprime = false;    
            else if(inputReceive <= 3){
                System.out.printf("%d \n",isprime);
                return;     
            }else if( inputReceive % 2 == 0 || inputReceive % 3 == 0)
                 isprime = false;
            while ((n*n)<inputReceive){
                if (inputReceive % n == 0 || inputReceive % (n + 2) == 0)
                isprime = false;

                n = n+6;
                isprime = true;
            }
            nextPrime++;
        }while(isprime = false);

        System.out.printf("Next prime number is %d",nextPrime);
    }
}
```

output given would be 45 and thats not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831192/java-program-for-prime-numbers?rq=1

Comment: can't say about the program, but this condition seems to be incorrect. `while(isprime = false);`

Comment: You have a lot of questions that you ask about inputReceive within the do...while loop. The answers to these questions will not change after the first iteration of the loop, since inputReceive is not changed. Getting rid of this problem will simplify your code and make it easier to see what's not working.

Comment: got any idea to what i should change it to? @Shashwat

Comment: adding onto @Shashwat comment, typically you'd do `while(!isprime)` but if you're not used to it then invert the condition like this `while( false == isprime)`, this way if you mistakenly try to assign a value to it, it should not compile.

Comment: isprime = false

Comment: `while(!isprime)` Note that I haven't seen the program, so the underlying logic may be wrong. @HassanRammal

Comment: alright so i update the code and still same thing... @JonKiparsky so what should i do? how would i change it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

```
while(isprime = false);
```

That's assignment, not equality testing. Since you're assigning `false`, this won't loop.

```
            n = n+6;
            isprime = true;
```

You do this unconditionally.

Expansion to follow.

Comment: `!isPrime` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring things already pointed out, you perform all of your checks on `inputRecieve` and never update it. You only unconditionally update `nextPrime` and moreover never check its primeness. Here is how I would do it:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x){
    boolean result = true;

    for(int i = 2; i<=Math.sqrt(x); i++){
        if((x % i) == 0){
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please insert a number:");
    int inputRecieve = sc.nextInt();

    boolean notPrime = true;

    while(notPrime){
        if(isPrime(++inputRecieve))
            notPrime = false;
    }

    System.out.println("Next prime number is: " + inputRecieve);

}
```